# Android Studio : Execution failed for task

Tags: android-studio

need help i have just installed my Android Studio. after creating a project ... than i face this problem.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\MF COMP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details this much is not sufficient and I think these aapt error are generated while program execution due to anonymous input by you